# How to remove particular categorical predictor in R in lm()?

Tags: r, variables, modeling

I am just starting out on linear modelling . I have the below regressor

```
regressor=lm(Profit~R.D.Spend+Administration+Marketing.Spend+State,data=dataset)
```

Now three state levels.

```
> levels(dataset$State)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Below is the output of my model , and i just need to remove state2 from it . How do i go about that ?

```
> summary(regressor)

Call:
lm(formula = Profit ~ R.D.Spend + Administration + Marketing.Spend + 
    State, data = dataset)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-33504  -4736     90   6672  17338 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      5.013e+04  6.885e+03   7.281 4.44e-09 ***
R.D.Spend        8.060e-01  4.641e-02  17.369  < 2e-16 ***
Administration  -2.700e-02  5.223e-02  -0.517    0.608    
Marketing.Spend  2.698e-02  1.714e-02   1.574    0.123    
State2           1.988e+02  3.371e+03   0.059    0.953    
State3          -4.189e+01  3.256e+03  -0.013    0.990
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: Its unclear what you want. Are you trying to estimate a model that only has a dummy variable for the case where `state==3`? Are you trying to change which category is dropped from the factor?

Comment: yes id like tofirst remove state2 as my SL>0.05. My question is how to i go about removing individual parts of a categorical variable . If state1=Newyork, state2=california and state3=florida what if i just want to view for Ny or cali @gfgm

Comment: Sate column initially was a categorical variable that had "New york","California" , "Florida". I altered them as factors and assigned labels 1,2,3

Comment: In the formula you use to specify the regression you can write `I(State=='3')` to create a dummy variable that is equal to 1 when the condition is true.

Comment: Thanks a  ton!!! u made my day !! :) @gfgm

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
regressor<-update(regressor,~.-State2)
summary(regressor)
```

Comment: but i dont wan to add it , state already has state1,state2 and state3 as dummy variables . i just want to remove state2 as part of backward elimination process